# LibGDX - sprite.setY() not exact

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

Well, i'm making a android game in LibGDX. I have a sprite and a variable.

```
  float barEnabledY = -678
```

Whenever I do :

```
  sprite.setY(barEnabledY);
```

On my Nexus 7, (about 50% of the time), the Y location of the sprite is not set to -678.  It's set to values like:
-677.9999
and
-678.0001

The problem does not occur on my Galaxy S4.

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Sounds like this could be related to [floating point arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 0):

That is definitely due to standard floating point "error", which is 100% normal and generally unavoidable.

Since it seems you are using it for pixel values (?) you can convert your values to integer before using them:

```
sprite.set( (int)( barEnabledY + 0.5f ) );
```

If you need to work with pixels it is usually best to use floats for all calculations (such as translation, rotation, etc) and then covert to integer for final usage (in screen space).

Generally though, these kinds of errors should not be a problem since the rasterization will automatically convert to integer - but you may get blurred results if you need pixel perfect rendering.